# How can I change the color of MUI styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have a MUI styled component that renders a green circular badge.

```
const StyledGreenBadge = styled(Badge)(({ theme }) => ({
    '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
      backgroundColor: '#44b700',
      color: '#44b700',
      width: '15px',
      height: '15px',
      borderRadius: '100%',
      boxShadow: `0 0 0 2px ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
      '&::after': {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        animation: 'ripple 1.2s infinite ease-in-out',
        border: '1px solid currentColor',
        content: '""',
      },
    },
    '@keyframes ripple': {
      '0%': {
        transform: 'scale(.8)',
        opacity: 1,
      },
      '100%': {
        transform: 'scale(2.4)',
        opacity: 0,
      },
    },
  }));
```

Now, I want my code to be DRY, so I want to create a StyledYellowBadge.

All I have to do is somehow just change the `color` property of StyledGreenBadge.

Yet, I could not figure out how for 3 hours.

I have tried something like this:

```
color: { desiredColor === 'yellow' ? 'yellow' : #44b700'},
```

where desiredColor is a second argument, after

```
{ theme }
```

How can I make achieve this?

Comment: Material UI allows you to add more colors to the palette, you can then access those extra colors using the color attribute on the components. If it's acceptable to just use attributes instead of styled components you can take a look at: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom properties to your styled MUI component by describing the type:

```
const StyledGreenBadge = styled(Badge)<{ badgeColor?: string }>(
```

Then, you can pass described property (`badgeColor` in this case) to your styled `Badge` component:

```
 <StyledGreenBadge badgeColor="red" badgeContent={4} color="primary">
```

and assign it to the property you want:

```
  backgroundColor: props.badgeColor ?? "#44b700",
```

Full code:

```
const StyledGreenBadge = styled(Badge)<{ badgeColor: string }>(
  ({ theme, ...props }) => {
    console.log(props);
    return {
      "& .MuiBadge-badge": {
        backgroundColor: props.badgeColor ?? "#44b700",
        color: "#44b700",
        width: "15px",
        height: "15px",
        borderRadius: "100%",
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 2px ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
        "&::after": {
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          borderRadius: "50%",
          animation: "ripple 1.2s infinite ease-in-out",
          border: "1px solid currentColor",
          content: '""'
        }
      },
      "@keyframes ripple": {
        "0%": {
          transform: "scale(.8)",
          opacity: 1
        },
        "100%": {
          transform: "scale(2.4)",
          opacity: 0
        }
      }
    };
  }
);

export default function SimpleBadge() {
  return (
    <StyledGreenBadge badgeColor="red" badgeContent={4} color="primary">
      <MailIcon color="action" />
    </StyledGreenBadge>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custombadgecolor-2cg246?file=/demo.tsx:169-1278)